# How to create mock object of such method which return type is List<Tuple>

Tags: spring-data-jpa, mockito, junit4, querydsl

I am trying to write test case for Account Controller. At very first My I am creating mock object but that methods return type is `List<Tuple>`. I am not getting how to create mock object of following method which return type is List

Can any one tell me how to create mock object for following method?

**AccountController**

```
    @GetMapping("/findAccountData")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Tuple>> populateGridViews(@RequestParam(value="sClientAcctId",required=false) String sClientAcctId,
                                                         @RequestParam(value="sAcctDesc",required=false) String sAcctDesc,
                                                         @RequestParam(value="sInvestigatorName",required=false)String sInvestigatorName,
                                                         @RequestParam(value="sClientDeptId",required=false) String sClientDeptId) throws Exception {
        return  ResponseEntity.ok(accService.populateGridViews(sClientAcctId, sAcctDesc,sInvestigatorName,sClientDeptId));
    }
```

**AccountService**

```
public List<Tuple> populateGridViews(String sClientAcctId, String sAcctDesc, String sInvestigatorName,
        String sClientDeptId)throws Exception{

    QAccount account = QAccount.account;
    QDepartment department = QDepartment.department;
    QAccountCPCMapping accountCPCMapping = QAccountCPCMapping.accountCPCMapping;
    QInvestigator investigator = QInvestigator.investigator;

    JPAQuery<Tuple> query = new JPAQuery<Tuple>(em);
    query.select(Projections.bean(Account.class, account.sClientAcctId, account.sAcctDesc, account.sLocation,
            Projections.bean(Department.class, department.sDeptName, department.sClientDeptId).as("department"),
            Projections.bean(Investigator.class, investigator.sInvestigatorName).as("investigator"),
            Projections.bean(AccountCPCMapping.class, accountCPCMapping.sCCPCode).as("accountCPC"))).from(account)
            .innerJoin(account.department, department).innerJoin(account.accountCPC, accountCPCMapping)
            .innerJoin(account.investigator, investigator);

    if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(sClientAcctId)) {
        query.where(account.sClientAcctId.equalsIgnoreCase(sClientAcctId));
    }
  // code.......


    return query.fetch();       

}
```

**AccountControllerTest**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class TestAccountController {

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Mock
    private AccountService accountService;

    @InjectMocks
    private AccountController accountController;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(accountController).build();
    }
       @Test
        public void populateGridViewsTest() throws Exception {

            String sClientAcctId = "1122";
            String sAcctDesc = "SRI";
            String sInvestigatorName = "Ram";
            String sClientDeptId = "1200";      

            Tuple mockedTuple = Mockito.mock(Tuple.class);      

            List<Tuple> accountObj = new ArrayList<>();
            accountObj.add(mockedTuple);

            Mockito.when(accountService.populateGridViews(sClientAcctId, sAcctDesc, sInvestigatorName, sClientDeptId))
                    .thenReturn(accountObj);

            mockMvc.perform(
                    get("/spacestudy/$ InstituteIdentifier/admin/account/findAccountData")
                    .param("sClientAcctId", "1122")
                    .param("sAcctDesc", "SRI")
                    .param("sInvestigatorName", "Ram")
                    .param("sClientDeptId", "1200")
                    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                    .andExpect(status().isOk())
                    .andDo(print());        

            Mockito.verify(accountService).populateGridViews(sClientAcctId, sAcctDesc, sInvestigatorName, sClientDeptId);

        }
```

Stack Trace

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException: 
when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.
For example:
    when(mock.getArticles()).thenReturn(articles);

Also, this error might show up because:
1. you stub either of: final/private/equals()/hashCode() methods.
   Those methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified.
   Mocking methods declared on non-public parent classes is not supported.
2. inside when() you don't call method on mock but on some other object.

    at com.spacestudy.controller.AccountControllerTest.populateGridViewsTest(AccountControllerTest.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:538)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:760)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:206)
```

Comment: Are you asking whether you should mock the List (you shouldn't mock Lists), or are you asking what kind of data should be contained within the Tuples?

Comment: I am asking about what should be return of mockito. and also what kind of data within tuple

Comment: The return object can simply be a `new ArrayList<Tuple>()`, which you can populate with Tuple objects you create. The structure of the Tuple depends on your query. The difficulty in returning the correct Tuple is why you might consider an in-memory database instead of simulating specific query calls with mocks.

Comment: `List<Tuple> accountObj = new ArrayList<>()` like this you are saying. then how to add data in that.

Comment: I tried to write test like above but here I am getting status 500 instead of 200 and `.andDo(print()); ` in console body getting null

Answer (score 1):

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class TestAccountController {
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private AccountService accountService;

    @Autowired
    private AccountController accountController;


       @Test
       @Transactional
        public void populateGridViewsTest() throws Exception {

            String sClientAcctId = "1122";
            String sAcctDesc = "SRI";
            String sInvestigatorName = "Ram";
            String sClientDeptId = "1200";      

            Tuple mockedTuple = Mockito.mock(Tuple.class);      

            List<Tuple> accountObj = new ArrayList<>();
            accountObj.add(mockedTuple);

            Mockito.when(accountService.populateGridViews(sClientAcctId, sAcctDesc, sInvestigatorName, sClientDeptId))
                    .thenReturn(accountObj);

            mockMvc.perform(
                    get("/spacestudy/$ InstituteIdentifier/admin/account/findAccountData")
                    .param("sClientAcctId", "1122")
                    .param("sAcctDesc", "SRI")
                    .param("sInvestigatorName", "Ram")
                    .param("sClientDeptId", "1200")
                    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                    .andExpect(status().isOk())
                    .andDo(print());        

            Mockito.verify(accountService).populateGridViews(sClientAcctId, sAcctDesc, sInvestigatorName, sClientDeptId);

        }
```

Comment: I am getting this exceptions `org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException:` I updated Quation with stack trace

Comment: only with one annotation you are saying

Comment: SpringUser , just try this i think it will work, remove   @InjectMocks on your AccountController and do like this, Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        accountController= new AccountController (accountService);
    }

Comment: I tried what you gave above in that there is no `@InjectMock`

Comment: ya remove @InjectMock, there no use of that and in setUp() method do what i gave before.. i think it will work

Answer (score 0):

```
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class TickServiceTest {
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;
}
```

First you have to try this..instead of using **Mockito** use **MockMvc** object. And just tell me u want to create **AccountController** object or **Account** bean object?

Comment: I updated my Test class, I am having all configuration. I added service class also. But I am not getting what mockito should return

Comment: if we use `@AutoConfigureMockMvc` then no need to create mock object

Comment: I updated my test class can you tell changes in that

Comment: MockMvc would only be used here if you are testing full integration testing, or unit testing the controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can implements Tuple interface and use it in thenReturn method.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

import com.querydsl.core.Tuple;
import com.querydsl.core.types.Expression;

public class MockedTuple implements Tuple {

    private final Object[] a;

    public MockedTuple(Object[] a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public <T> T get(int index, Class<T> type) {
        return (T) a[index];
    }

    @Override
    public <T> T get(Expression<T> expr) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return a.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object[] toArray() {
        return a;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == this) {
            return true;
        } else if (obj instanceof Tuple) {
            return Arrays.equals(a, ((Tuple) obj).toArray());
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Arrays.hashCode(a);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return Arrays.toString(a);
    }

}
```

Example of test:

```
Object[] myReturnedObject = new Object[1];
myReturnedObject[0] = value;

when(myService.getTuples(...params)).thenReturn(
List.of(new MockedTuple(myReturnedObject))
)
```